# Is there any API that i can distinguish between 3G Network and Wifi?

Tags: ipad, networking, wifi, 3g

I am working with my ipad app. With my iPad 3G,it's a trouble that i can't solve. I want to distinguish between 3G network and wifi in my app. Anyone had encountered the same problem before? any advice welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the ["reachability" API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) that is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking).

Comment: Did you follow both links I gave you? The second link (to another question here on StackOverflow) even gives a complete code listing that shows the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want to confirm this questions again. Because I am at home now and don't have 3G card to verify.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/08/reachability/

Comment: Yes, WWAN and 3G/EDGE are interchangeable.

Comment: WWAN status comes when you turn on airplane mode.

Comment: @iKT I get NotReachable with Airplane Mode on (iOS 10.3.3)

Answer (score -4):

You can use this to distinguish 3G or WIFI network~

```
//For 3G check
boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
        .isConnectedOrConnecting();
//For WiFi Check
boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        .isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: Absolutely, your code are for android. My question is about iOS.