# How can I tell when an iPhone loses or re-acquires an Internet connection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, events

Is there an event or notifier that I can have my app listen for that will tell me when the device I'm running on loses an Internet connection or re-acquires a connection?

What I've found so far are posts that tell me how to retrieve the current status of the connection, to have my app reach out and ask the system whether there is a connection, but I can't find anything about an event *from* the device's OS that I can just have my app listen for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for "Reachability".  It sends a notification whenever the status changes.  You can either add observers for that notification, or add one to translate the state into your own notifications.  See the accepted answer for:  [iPhone reachability checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking)