# Troubleshooting to connect and disconnect to network

Tags: iphone

Suppose I have a application which fetch data from network and then showing those data in application. But sometimes internet becomes disconnected so I am showing message that 'Internet not available'. But I want to keep user busy with the application. So I want to do following things but there are some problem in implementation.

1) When network disconnected I want to show message 'network disconnect' and I want to store all data in db.
  Problem: How will I know network is not available without happening any event?

2) And when network is connected I want to fetch data and store in buffer.
  Problem : Same, how will I know network is available rightnow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite common question and is best solved using `Reachability` class.

You can find a nice manual here: [Testing Network Reachability](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/)

And a quick answer is the accepted answer here:

[iPhone reachability checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking)

But be aware that it's best to check for host availabiility. I tested this code when device was connected to AdHoc WiFi (with no internet connectivity) and the result was: internet available via WiFi. So if you want to be sure - use host status.

EDIT: and this is probably the best example on SO (answer from iWasRobbed):

[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)