# AVPlayer detect lost connection

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using the AVPlayer object in iOS 6.1. I am currently connecting to an Icecast server to stream a live music feed. However when the stream goes down for any reason (such as a restart or change of signal) the AVPlayer stops playing. I have tried adding an observer for "status" but that only seams to be called whenever I start or stop the player. Is there a way to detect the lost connection so I can reconnect the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

this post shows how to implement it
[iphone-reachability-checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking)