# how to check if net is disconnected the show alert and stop the method

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I am making an app in which i upload data to server from the iphone app I want that if user uploads data while internet is connected and suddenly internet is disconnected then it should show alert rather than crashing the app.
For to check network at starch we can use Reachbility class but what if it disconnects during process.

Comment: Raechability Class use to check Network Available or not

Comment: You can use AFNetworking Which is directly check Network is available or not also give alert message

Comment: @KiritModi but if I have method test() which uploads data when internet is on but just it starts upload net is disconnected to how to tackel tha t

Comment: in AFNetworking its default show when disconnect internet. you have not implement code . code is default in AFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the Reachability class. You can download it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Check on how to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking).

Answer (score 0):

Use great libraries like [AFNetwork](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [ASIHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). This libraries provide support for handling internet connection failure in most recommended way.